# I don't understand why my (slqrs1.next()) is returning the last row data

Tags: java, sql

I've implemented my code so that it returns a response object New Response(Boolean Type,String Type, List clientsinfo = new ArrayList<>() ) . But the response only returns me the last row added "the number of iterations times" in my ArrayList() objects . I don't understand why . I'm trying to add objects taken from my database through a while loop in a while loop but it only adds the last row .I don't understand why and i need some help please. This is the code below :

```
 public Response all_clients_with_accounts() throws SQLException
         {
           List<Object> clientinfos = new ArrayList<Object>();
             String sql1= "select * from client" ;//Clients info
             String sql2="select * from datatab1 where clientId =? ";
             String sql3="select * from datatab2 where clientId = ?";
           
             try 
             {
                 Statement st1= con.createStatement();
                 ResultSet sqlrs1 = st1.executeQuery(sql1);
                 PreparedStatement pstmt2 = con.prepareStatement(sql2);
                 PreparedStatement pstmt3 = con.prepareStatement(sql3);
                 while(sqlrs1.next())
                 {
                     
                    
                     Client client = new Client ();
                   client.setId(sqlrs1.getInt(1));
                   client.setNom(sqlrs1.getString(2));
                   client.setPrenom(sqlrs1.getString(3));
                   client.setCnib(sqlrs1.getString(4));
                   client.setContact(sqlrs1.getString(5));
                   client.setProfession(sqlrs1.getString(6));
                   client.setVille(sqlrs1.getString(7));
                   client.setRole(sqlrs1.getString(8));
                   client.setAgentCode(sqlrs1.getString(9));
                   client.setDate(sqlrs1.getString(10));
                   client.setBirthday(sqlrs1.getString(11));
                   
                   clientaccountinfo.setClient(client);
                 
                  
                 
                  pstmt2.setInt(1,client.getId());
                  ResultSet rs2 = pstmt2.executeQuery();
                  
                   if(rs2.next())
                   {
                       Accountclass accountclass = new Accountclass();
                       accountclass.setTransactionId(rs2.getInt(1));
                       accountclass.setClientId(rs2.getInt(2));
                       accountclass.setWallet(rs2.getString(3));
                       accountclass.setSolde(rs2.getDouble(4));
                       accountclass.setDebit(rs2.getDouble(5));
                       accountclass.setCredit(rs2.getDouble(6));
                       
                       clientaccountinfo.setOrange(accountclass);
                       
                   }
                   
                   
                  
                 
                  pstmt3.setInt(1,client.getId());
                  ResultSet rs3 = pstmt3.executeQuery();
                  
                   if(rs3.next())
                   {
                       Accountclass accountclass = new Accountclass();
                       accountclass.setTransactionId(rs3.getInt(1));
                       accountclass.setClientId(rs3.getInt(2));
                       accountclass.setWallet(rs3.getString(3));
                       accountclass.setSolde(rs3.getDouble(4));
                       accountclass.setDebit(rs3.getDouble(5));
                       accountclass.setCredit(rs3.getDouble(6));
                      
                       
                       clientaccountinfo.setMobicash(accountclass);
                       
                       
                       
                   }
                  
                  
                    clientinfos.add(clientaccountinfo);
                  
                 
                 }
               
                  
                return new Response(true,"Informations about client",clientinfos);
                 
             }
             catch (Exception e)
             {
                 e.printStackTrace();
               return new Response(false,"Error", null);
                 
             }
             finally
             {
                 con.close();
             }
```

Comment: The link you have given doesn't contain the solution of my problem

Comment: It does answer your question, you are adding `clientaccountinfo` over and over again to the list, while you are overwriting its client, orange and mobiChas on each iteration, so the last update "wins". You will need to create a new `clientaccountinfo` (whatever it is) in each iteration.